# Finite summation including binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to solve the summation below, but I can't get a nice algebraically reduced equation.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{k}} $$
I have tried to convert this into $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cfrac{2n-4k+1}{(2n-2k+1)\binom{2n}{2k-1}}$ by combining every two successive terms into one.

Comment: What attempts have you made? If you can include the things you've tried in the statement of your question, even if you couldn't get them to work, we will be able to provide help that will be more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that
$$\int_0^1 t^p (1-t)^q \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{(p+q+1)\binom{p+q}{p}}$$
for nonnegative integers $p$ and $q$.
So
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{k}}
=& \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{2n+1}{(2n+1)\binom{k+(2n-k)}{k}} \\
=& (2n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1}\int_0^1 t^k (1-t)^{2n-k} \mathrm{d}t \\
=& (2n+1)\int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1}t^k (1-t)^{2n-k} \mathrm{d}t \\
=& (2n+1)\int_0^1 (-t^{2n+1} + t(1-t)^{2n}) \mathrm{d}t \\
=& (2n+1)\int_0^1 \left(-t^{2n+1} + (1-t)t^{2n}\right) \mathrm{d}t \\
=& (2n+1)\int_0^1 \left(-2t^{2n+1} + t^{2n}\right) \mathrm{d}t \\
=& (2n+1)\left.\left(\frac{-2t^{2n+2}}{2n+2}+\frac{t^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right)\right|_0^1 \\ 
=& (2n+1)\left(\frac{-2}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right) \\
=& -\frac{n}{n+1}.
\end{align}